# Existence of Nash equilibrium in n-person concave game.

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, game-theory, nash-equilibrium, set-valued-analysis

In order to show the existence of Nash equilibrium in a continuous game for concave objective functions (Theorem.1. (Rosen 1965) ), i found a result that says that the function $\Gamma $ is upper semicontinuous, where :

$\Gamma(x)=\{y \in E|\rho(x,y)=\displaystyle\max_{z\in E}\rho(x,z)\}$

Here we note that:

$\bullet\:\Gamma : E\rightarrow P(E)$

$\bullet\:E=\displaystyle\Pi_{i\in N}^{n}E_{i}\:\:$ avec $E_{i}\subset\mathbb{R}$ is convex, compact  $\forall i\in \{1,...n\}$

$\bullet\:\rho : E\times E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is concave in $y$ for each fixed $x \in E$

$\bullet\:\rho$ is continuous in $E\times E$

So my question is:

How to show that **$\Gamma$ is upper semicontinuous** ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Using Berge’s Maximum Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_theorem.

Comment: thank you for your help @AsAnExerciseProve but yet the results that I found are related to the hemicontinuity of the function but not to its semicontinuity, so what I wanted to know is there a difference between the hemicontinuity and semicontinuity of a set-valued function

Comment: @mus The book "A First Course in Optimization Theory" by Rangarajan K. Sundaram has the exact result you want (Theorem 9.14). Unfortunately, the definition of hemicontinous is not agreed upon. Page 6 of https://healy.econ.ohio-state.edu/kcb/Notes/Correspondences.pdf lists various different uses of the word. The book above defines semi cont to mean hemi cont. The Rosen 1965 paper doesn't define what they mean by semicontinuous. The result you are asking about is a well know result so I'm pretty sure it is the result in "A First Course in Optimization Theory" Theorem 9.14

Comment: Exactly, thank you for your help @AsAnExerciseProve, I found some interesting results in this book